# StartsWith in Select Query

Tags: soql, query

In a test class I inserted a product record in the testSetup and another one in the method. When I query the product I need to filter to get to the one record I want to assert against. The solution in the query is to filter it somehow with a WHERE clause. I want to filter on the Product Name and thought I could use startsWith but I'm having trouble getting the right syntax. The only examples that seem to be on stackexchange and developer docs is using it in an assert.

How can I write a query to use starts with?

Example class:

```
@isTest static void error(){

    // Create a product record
    Product2 proderr = new Product2();
        proderr.Name = 'Womp Womp';
        proderr.Product_LOB__c = '';
        proderr.Product_Type__c = 'Subscription';
        proderr.Product_Launch_Date__c = System.today();
        proderr.Product_Data_Source__c = 'Other';
    insert proderr;

    // Get the Product Error record
    Product2 prod = [SELECT Id,
                            Name,
                            Product_LOB__c,
                            Product_BU__c,
                            Product_Sector__c
                    FROM Product2
                    WHERE Name = String.startsWith('Womp')];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answers do directly answer your question but you may want to change your thinking when it comes to querying for records during a test method.

In almost all cases you will know the IDs of the records you need to assert for.

While you may currently think that the `Like` query is safe, if you use the same logic for another object, say opportunity, and an admin adds a workflow rule or code to standardize the naming format of the record (a common practice), your test will being to fail as the name was changed and the records would not be found via the `Like` operator.

- If you want the product created during setup use `ID != {Method Product ID}`
- If you want the product created in the method use id = {Method Product ID}.

Best practice would be to use the ID to query for the record. It will ensure that your tests survive changes made in the org that are out of your control.

There may be cases where you would not know the ID but I have yet to find any during my tests as I always know the IDs records created or at least something more concrete than a `Like` in my query to find them.

In summary, while Like may get you what you want this time, following that practice as a habit will come back to bite you down the road

Comment: This is solid advice.

Answer (score 22):

Use `LIKE` with a wildcard (`%`).

```
WHERE Name LIKE 'Womp%'
```

This particular wildcard means "zero or more characters"

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, wildcard characters can be used with the SQL LIKE operator.

SQL wildcards are used to search for data within a table.

With SQL, the wildcards are:

['%']           A substitute for zero or more characters

['_']           A substitute for a single character

[(charlist)]    Sets and ranges of characters to match

[^(charlist)]
or
[!(charlist)]   Matches only a character NOT specified within the brackets

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Why are you talking about `SQL`? It has nothing to do with the question. Typo? The query language in `Apex` is called `SOQL`.